# BCP command in powershell

Tags: bash, powershell, bcp

In bash, I am using the following bcp command to create an XML format:

```
bcp DATABASE.[UserData] format nul -c -x -f F:\UsageExports\UserData.xml -t, -T
```

However, when I run the same command in Powershell, I get the error: *Missing argument in parameter list*

I also tried executing the command without in Powershell:

```
bcp DATABASE.[UserData] format nul -c -x -f F:\UsageExports\UserData.xml -t -T
```

However, the -t tag does not work and the terminator is not included in the XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell can be rather picky when it comes to passing arguments to an external command. Usually the best way of dealing with such a situation is to define an array with the arguments and then [splat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0) that array on the command:

```
$params = 'DATABASE.[UserData]', 'format', 'nul', '-c', '-x',
          '-f', 'F:\UsageExports\UserData.xml', '-t,', '-T'

& bcp @params
```

In your case the issue is probably caused by the argument `,` for the parameter `-t`. A comma in PowerShell is used for constructing arrays. I would guess that `-t, -T` is interpreted as `@('-t', '-T')` and then mangled to `'-t -T'` when the external command is invoked.